# Rails form_tag to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app where I have a partial that I want a dropdown in so when a user is selected it will do a get method to the urls /timecards/:user_id which will be the controller's show method passing in the User's id field.  I'm having a hard time with my paths in the `form_tag` and could use some help.

Here is my partial in the view:

```
<%= form_tag timecard_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(User.employee.order("username ASC"), :id, :username) %>
  <%= submit_tag "View Employee", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

From rake routes I get the following output:

```
timecards GET    /timecards(.:format)                 timecards#index
                           POST   /timecards(.:format)                 timecards#create
              new_timecard GET    /timecards/new(.:format)             timecards#new
             edit_timecard GET    /timecards/:id/edit(.:format)        timecards#edit
                  timecard GET    /timecards/:id(.:format)             timecards#show
                           PUT    /timecards/:id(.:format)             timecards#update
                           DELETE /timecards/:id(.:format)             timecards#destroy
```

Here is my controller: timecards_controller.rb

```
class TimecardsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :disallow_clients, :disallow_medics, :disallow_employee, :disallow_supervisor

  def index
    @clock_events = ClockEvent.includes(:user).search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          @clock_events = @clock_events.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page] || 20, :page => params[:page]).order('users.username asc').order('clock_in desc')
        end
        format.csv { send_data ClockEvent.to_csv(@clock_events.order('users.username asc').order('clock_in desc')) }
      end
  end

  def new
    @clock_event = ClockEvent.new
  end

  def create
    parse_times!
    @clock_event = ClockEvent.new(params[:clock_event])

     if @clock_event.save
       redirect_to timecard_path(@clock_event.user.id), notice: "Entry added for #{@clock_event.user.username}".html_safe
      else
       render :new, notice: "Time Card Entry failed to Save".html_safe
      end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @clock_events = @user.clock_events.search(params[:search])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          @clock_events = @clock_events.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page] || 5, :page => params[:page]).order('clock_in DESC')
        end
        format.csv { send_data ClockEvent.to_csv(@clock_events.order('clock_in desc')) }
        format.pdf do
          pdf = TimeCardPdf.new(@clock_events, @user)
          send_data pdf.render, filename: "timecard-#{@user.username}",
                                type: "application/pdf",
                                disposition: "inline"
         end
      end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @clock_events = @user.clock_events.search(params[:search]).order("clock_in ASC").paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end

  def update
    parse_times!
    @clock_event = ClockEvent.find(params[:clock_event][:id])
    if @clock_event.update_attributes(params[:clock_event])
        redirect_to edit_timecard_path(@clock_event.user.id), notice: "Updated Successfully".html_safe
    else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Woops.".html_safe
    end
  end

  private

  def parse_times!
    params[:clock_event].parse_time_select! :clock_in if params[:clock_event].has_key? 'clock_in(5i)'
    params[:clock_event].parse_time_select! :clock_out if params[:clock_event].has_key? 'clock_out(5i)'
  end

end
```

So I believe I'm calling the path properly in the `form_tag` but when I load the page I get the error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"timecards"}` Even though there is a show action in the timecards_controller.

I think something I have to set the `form_tag` for an explicit url and somehow pass in the `:id` of the user in the params.  But I'm a bit stuck on how to do this.

So to summarize.  When I have the dropdown, I select a user, click "View Employee", and that should go to the show action in timecards_controller.rb with the url of /timecards/3 (as an example).  I've never used form_tag in this way before so passing a path or explicit url is a bit foreign to me.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your controller?

Comment: @ArslanAli I've updated with my controller code, thanks for looking!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A simple hotfix:

The simplest possible fix would be to change the form to a bunch of links.

```
<%= User.employee.order("username ASC").each |u| %>
  <%= link_to u.username, timecard_path %>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise you could use Javascript to simply make the form redirect:

```
<%= form_tag timecodes_path, :method => :get, :id => 'timecode_employee' do %>
  <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(User.employee.order("username ASC"), :id, :username) %>
  <%= submit_tag "View Employee", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
$("#timecode_employee").submit(function(e){
  var form = $(this);
  // redirect to timecards/:id
  window.location = form.attr('action') + form.find('select').val();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

### Tips for redesign

Your design could be radically improved by adding an underlying TimeCard model.

Here is one very common case which tells you why:

> The client decides that they want to have managers sign off on time
>   cards every month.

Oh, drat. Now we need get all the `ClockEvents` in that scope and update a 'clock_events.state' on each.

But then the client also wants to know who has signed off the card. So you add a `clock_events.signed_off_by_id` and update all the clockevents. And then they want three managers to sign off, etc.

## An alternative design

Note that this is a opinionated generic example.

```
class ClockEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:clocked_in, :clocked_out]
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :time_card
end

class TimeCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :clock_events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clock_events
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_cards
  has_many :clock_events, through: :time_cards
end
```

A TimeCard might be automatically issued per month or if you never want to change than just stick with one TimeCard per user.
Lets go with some traditional routes here:

```
resources :time_cards
end
resources :clock_events do
end
resources :users, shallow: true do
  resources :clock_events do
  end
  resources :time_cards do
  end
end
```

Now imagine we had a classical punch card time clock.

We would punch in with:

```
POST /clock_events { user_id: 1, time_card_id: 5 }
```

And punch out with:

```
PATCH /clock_events/1 { status: :clocked_out }
```

Thats REST for you.

### Nesto Presto

We have nested routes for time cards and clock_events per user:

```
GET /users/1/time_cards
GET /users/1/clock_events
```

From the we can choose to either build a dedicated `UserTimeCardController` or we can scope by the user id param in TimeCardsController.

```
class TimeCardsController
  def index
    @time_cards = TimeCard.all
    @time_cards = @time_cards.where(user: params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
    @users = scope.all
  end
end
```

### Filtering

But imagine if we want managers be be able filter the number of employees he sees on the index - a good architecture would look something like this:

```
class TimeCardsController
  def index
    @time_cards = TimeCard.all
    @time_cards = @time_cards.where(user: params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id] 
    if params[:filters]
       @time_cards = @time_cards.search(params[:search])
    end
  end
end
```

And on our index page we would add a form like this:

```
<%= form_tag(time_cards_path, method: :get) %>
  <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(User.employee.order("username ASC"), :id, :username), multiple: true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Note, this is a rough sketch. To keep an already long answer readable I have omitted a bunch of stuff like authorization and how to actually do the filtering in the last step. You should look in to CanCanCan or Pundit for authorization and Rolify for managing roles. But thats out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: This is excellent.  I will definitely review this for future design patterns.  Unfortunately I am under the gun to have this rushed out by 1pm today so I don't think I'll have time to redesign.  I'm getting ready to leave my job so I'm working on a way to make things restful and still using the convoluted design I came up with.  Unfortunately I was given 3 days to finish this functionality so I'm chomping at the bit and struggled with the form_tag because I'm breaking restful/rails conventions.

Comment: Wait a second, the url in your form url  should be `timecards_path` if it is supposed to go to `timecards#index` where you have your search functionality.

Comment: This is really good work.  Had I more time I would rewrite the entire functionality this way.  It's so much cleaner and restful but I'm trying to ship today :(

Comment: @maxcal Actually the hotfix is what I decided to go with.  However your JS was off, it was redirecting to /timecards3 so I injected a `/` in it like this `window.location = form.attr('action') + '/' + form.find('select').val();`  Works like a charm and does exactly what I need it to do. :)  Shipping it now

Comment: I forgot that the path helpers don't have a trailing slash ;) Happy it worked out for you.

Comment: @maxcal You my friend are awesome and taught me a lot in this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The route that you have defined:

```
timecard GET    /timecards/:id(.:format)             timecards#show
```

It requires an `id` to show the correct timecard. But when you are invoking it in `form_tag`, you are just sending, `timecard_path` with no `id`. So you do need to send an `id` or a `timecard` object, and Rails will automatically extract the `id` out of it.

So, that should be:

```
form_tag @timecard do
  # other code
end
```

`@timecard` must be instantiated in the action that renders your partial, and it must be a valid `TimeCard` object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand that the route requires an id to show the correct user's timecard.  I tried `form_tag @timecard do` and in the controller I instantiated @timecard like so `@timecard = User.employee` and I get the following error: `undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class`

Comment: @cz3ch it sounds like you have defined the employee relation on User as has_many.

Comment: @cz3ch `@timecard` must be an object instantiated from `Timecard` model. I've no idea what `User.employee` returns, or how can you even call `employee` on `User` at class level?

Comment: `User.employee` returns a scope of all users who have a `role` that is not `medic` like so. `  scope :employee, -> { where('role != ?', 'medic') }
`  That's how I'm calling employee on User.  The problem with instantiating is there is no TimeCard model.  TimeCards is simply a controller that let's me look at the ClockEvent and User model.  So yes, I'm breaking Rails conventions here, but need to figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty convoluted design - I would definitely add a TimeCard model.

Comment: But in that case you actual have to get an instance of user `timecard_path(User.employee.last)`, but it's got a really bad code smell.

Comment: @cz3ch I agree with @maxcal. You need to have a `Timecard` model calss.

Comment: I agree the design is convoluted and does not follow (in fact it breads) Rails conventions.  But if I create a TimeCard model class, I'm not even sure what to instantiate from the model since I'm trying to get the User.id into this form tag.  Seems like a lot of work to to instantiate something.  Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly.  I appreciate any guidance.  Again, this is the first time I've had to use a `form_tag` in this manner.

Comment: I'm writing up a answer with an alternative design.

Comment: @maxcal Thank you, I appreciate your input, bigtime.  I think my design is the constraint right now.  I'm breaking the Rails "magic" :)

Comment: @maxcal Let me know what you come up with.  I'm coming up with another way to link/search to the employees by adding a search collection route under timecards then doing some sort of text search to pull the employee.  Then once the employees are listed, I pass in the user object to the `timecard_path`.  So far it's working but it's not as clean as a simple search from the main index action/view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely going to take @maxcal's advice and rewrite this thing, but since I had to ship fast I came up with an ugly UI hack that "works".  I don't like it but it does exactly what I need it to do.

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-medium btn-primary">View Employees</button>
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @users.each do |u| %>
      <li><%= link_to "#{u.username}", timecard_path(u) %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I don't like all the loading and this is really dirty, but in this instance since I was breaking all sorts of Rails conventions and had to ship this afternoon it'll work until I can come back and make it better.

Let the laughs begin. :)